Detailed derivation of ESCK gravity and Extended Friedmann Equations with Torsion
Do you know a textbook on the Einstein-Cartan-Sciama-Kibble theory of Gravitation and its application to derive Extended Friedmann Equations with Torsion, which shows the calculations in detail?

Maybe these docs could be of some help: https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.5423v2, https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4595, https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0587v2
